# How to change a value in a Task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have an `async` function. There are multiple levels of function calls that all return a `Task`. At some point in this chain I must modify the value of the result. I would like to do this without interrupting the flow of the `async` functions. Observe:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetWeb")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetResult([FromUri] string url)
{
    var result = await GetPageText(url);
    return Ok(result);
}

private Task<string> GetPageText(string url)
{
    Task<string> data = GetDataAsync(url);
    //here I would like to manipulate the data variable
    return data;
}
```

In the function `GetPageText` how do I manipulate the data variable without interrupting the asynchronous flow. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to `await` it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change a task's value, you need to create a new one. The `async` way of doing it is awaiting the original result and marking the method as `async` (that's only the case when you need the result of the original task):

```
private async Task<string> GetPageText(string url)
{
    var result = await GetDataAsync(url);
    return result + "bar";
}
```